# How in the third call temp2->next is able to access the address of the second node when the address was destroyed because of local scope?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

```
struct node {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int height;
    node* next; // Pointer to the next node
};
node* startPTR = NULL; // global

void addNode_AT_END() {
    node *temp1;
    node *temp2;

    temp1 = new node;  

    cout << "Enter the name : ";
    cin  >> temp1->name;
    cout << endl << "Enter the age : ";
    cin  >> temp1->age;
    cout << endl << "Enter height : ";
    cin  >> temp1->height;

    temp1->next = NULL;

    if( startPTR == NULL) {
       startPTR = temp1; 
    }  else {
       temp2 = startPTR;

       while( temp2->next != NULL )
           temp2 = temp2->next;

       temp2->next = temp1;
    }
 }
```

In this snippet , when the function is called the third time , else part works. The address of the `startPTR` is assigned to the `temp2`. Now what does `temp2->next` contain when the condition is being checked in the while loop? (during third call) If you say it contains the address of the second node , please tell how does it know the address of the second node,because we had assigned the address of the second node to the first node during the second call to the function using the statement `temp2->next = temp1` but because of it's local scope we loose the address.

This is the way i am currently thinking.Please explain how the condition is checked during the third call to the function and how the linked list is being formed?

Comment: [Linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list "Linked list")

Comment: (This might just be a case wherein this spelling of "loose" is correct...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only the pointer variables `temp1` and `temp2` that are of local scope. The actual linked-list nodes (of type `struct node`) are allocated on the heap via the call to `new`. Heap allocated data persists until it's free'd via a call to `delete`.

This means that the line `temp2->next = temp1` is storing the address of the new node that's appended to the tail of the list, and this information will be available on subsequent calls to the function `addNode_AT_END`.

The code seems to have a variety of issues - you're using global variables, unless there are subsequent calls to `delete` somewhere you have memory leaks, there's already the std container class `std::list` that's available...

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Regarding your comment - when you make a call `new node` you are constructing a `node` object on the heap. This object will available for use until a subsequent call to `delete` is made.

When you make the call `temp2->next = temp1` the following is true:

1. `temp2` points to the address in memory where the last node in the list is stored (this node would have been created by the call to `new` on the last iteration).
2. The value of the pointer variable `temp1` is assigned as the `next` pointer for the last node in the list (the data "pointed to" by `temp2`). This means that the address is stored on the **heap**, not within the local `temp2` pointer varaible.

When your function exits, yes the local pointer variables `temp1` and `temp2` go out of scope, but the **heap** allocated linked-list nodes are not destroyed - and this is where the addresses are stored.

EDIT: Second comment - in the `else` branch of the function, the pointer `temp2` is initialised to point to the head of the list with the line `temp2 = startPTR;`

The next lines (the `while` loop) traverse the linked-list from the head node until the pointer `temp2` points to the last node in the list (until `temp2->next = NULL`)

At this stage the new node is appended to the list, as discussed above.

Comment: `"This means that the line temp2->next = temp1 is storing the address of the new node that's appended to the tail of the list, and this information will be available on subsequent calls to the function addNode_AT_END"` Can you please elaborate in your answer that how this information will be available on the subsequent calls ? I am not clear about it,b'coz the information corresponding to this statment is lost

Comment: @ Darren Engwirda I understand this. But can you tell, during 3rd call and when the statement `temp2->next` is encountered in the while loop, how does that statement point to the address of second node. I mean the address of the second node is stored in the heap and how does `temp2->next` know it has to point towards that position _(towards the address of second node)_ in heap ?

Comment: @ Darren Engwirda you didn't answer my second comment. I didn't ask that.I know that is what the while loop is meant for. I am asking how the statement `temp2->next` know where to point during the 3rd call and when in the argument of while loop? _(or how does it know the address of the second node somewhere stored in the heap during the second call to the function with the statement `temp2->next=temp1`)_

Comment: @Suhail: This goes back to the original edit. You assign a `next` pointer each time you add a new node to the list. The line `temp2->next = temp1` (the last line in your function) adds a new node to the list by assigning the `next` pointer for the current tail node in the list. The new node that was added becomes the new tail node.

Answer (score 1):

During the third call, `temp2->next` in the first iteration of the while loop does point to the second node. The key here is the line

`temp1 = new node;`

When you use the `new` operator, this allocates an object on the heap (dynamic allocation) and gives you back a pointer to it. Anything that is allocated on the heap using `new` persists until you use `delete` on a pointer to that memory. Now the variable `temp1` itself is actually just a pointer on the stack which is a local variable. This only means that the pointer `temp1` will go out of scope, but you already pointed the first node's `next` pointer to the second node object that was on the heap, so it is still there.

Comment: `"but you already pointed the first node's next pointer to the second node object that was on the heap, so it is still there." what do you exactly mean by this line."` Please make it clear